# Multidimensional array not being POSTed

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am constructing a multidimensional array and trying to send it via ajax with other bits of data.

Here is how my array is created:

```
var filelist = new Array;

    $(this).find('input[name=filename]').each(function(index) {
        var fileinfo = new Array;
        fileinfo['src'] = $(this).data('src');        
        fileinfo['name'] = $(this).val(); 
        filelist.push(fileinfo);
    });
```

If I echo this out to console, it looks correct.

Then the AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'my_url_here',
        data: { id: id, files: filelist },
    })
```

Using Chrome Inspector, I can see the ID being passed along in the form data section, but the files array isn't.

What gives?

Comment: what scope is filelist in?  post more complete code

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but why is `fileinfo` an array rather than an object?

Comment: Well I'm picking up the data in PHP (CodeIgniter to be precise). I'll try filelist as an object, but will that solve the issue?

Comment: are you sure the `.each` happens before the ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help if you added more context to your code and the scope surrounding it.

The way you are using `filelist` is not as an array. Why not use a traditional object?

```
var filelist = [];

 $(this).find('input[name=filename]').each(function(index) {
     var fileinfo = {};
     fileinfo.src = $(this).data('src');        
     fileinfo.name = $(this).val(); 
     filelist.push(fileinfo);
 });
```

You can see it working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/TwoToneBytes/hMs3y/

The reason it's not working as expected however is due to the fact that you are just setting the `src` and `name` properties on the array. When jQuery goes to convert the array to a string it will just be an empty array because nothing was ever actually added to it.

```
var anArray = [];
anArray['foo'] = 'bar';
anArray['bar'] = 'foo';


console.log(anArray.length); // == 0 due to array abuse
console.log(JSON.stringify(anArray)); // returns [] because JSON.stringify is doing for(i<anArray.length) which is 0
```

Comment: This worked, but why? Why didn;t an array of array work, and why did an object containing arrays fail? Only an array of objects worked... Very odd!

Comment: This might explain it: http://jsfiddle.net/TwoToneBytes/K2pXw/1/. Basically since you're not actually pushing anything to the array it's length is not updated. So JSON.stringify returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Json is elegant way to do this type of thing:

e.g

```
Array
```

`(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [product_model] => HFJ5G1.5
            [product_type] => plat
            [product_return] => graviteits`

```
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 2
        [product_model] => HHJ5S2.5
        [product_type] => holle plunjer
        [product_return] => veer       

    )
);
```

This can be encoded to json using

```
json_encode($array);
```

The json will look like:

```
{"1":{"product_id":"1","product_model":"HFJ5G1.5","product_type":"plat","product_return":"graviteits"},"2":{"product_id":"2","product_model":"HHJ5S2.5","product_type":"holle plunjer","product_return":"veer"}}
```

Json makes life more easy for posting and handling the posted data on server side.